# Why is it possible to define a Property instance on the class-level but not load properties into it?

Tags: java

While playing around with Java, I noticed that I can create a new instance of Properties in the public class; however, when I try to load properties into the Properties instance it does not work, and only works in `public void bla()`. I have created an example code with comments to illustrate my confusion:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Foo {
    Properties myProps = new Properties(); // Can create the instance here (but can't load properties into it)
    myProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/bla.properties")); // Does not work: Invalid method declaration


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public void bla() throws IOException {

        myProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/bla.properties")); // works
        myProps.forEach(myProps::put);
    }
}
```

My initial attempt was to load some constants (on the class-level), such as adding properties. And then referencing these loaded properties in other method to avoid code duplication.

I understand this probably has nothing to do with properties. I'm rather trying to understand the syntax in Java.

Comment: That has nothing to do with properties but that it is simply not valid java Syntax to write method calls like above in the top level of the class. Its the same error as if you would try to just write `System.out.println("Foo");` in that line. The load method call can either be put in a Constructor or an initialization block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a static block

```
public class Foo {
    static Properties myProps = new Properties();
    
    static { 
         myProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/bla.properties")); 
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you would use a constructor

```
public class Foo {
    Properties myProps = new Properties();
    
    public Foo() { 
         myProps.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/bla.properties")); 
    }
}
```

Note: `src/main/resources` does not exist when code is compiled, and that is not how to reference a file off the classpath

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the file reference part! I will cover the correct way to reference resources as a separate question (if not already exists). What is more idiomatic or preferred? It is not clear to me when should I use a static block vs. a constructor?

Comment: Rule of thumb: static variables belong to every instance of the Foo class. Constructors and non-static fields belong to a single instance, which could be turned into a singleton if you only want one instance at any time.

Comment: To make sure I got this correctly. If I use a static block, I can reference myProps form anywhere, for example like: `Foo.myProps.setProperty("hi", "bye");`. But I can't think of an example where I would use a constructor. How would I reference myProps that used the constructor (without making the class static)?

Comment: You shouldn't use a public static field. You would use a getter method on the instance to access otherwise